# Як підключити пакети в Python

Tags: python

Як підключити пакети mne, ketas,  urllib3?

Comment: Тут прийнято ставити запитання російською. Будь ласка перекладіть запитання на російську мову.

Comment: если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста отметьте его

Answer (score 2):

Для начала необходимо скачать его через pip (установить его, если отсутсвует). Для установки библиотек в консоли пишется:

```
pip install *имя пакета*
```

Например:

```
pip install mne ketas urllib3
```

Затем для включения их в коде необходимо написать:

```
import *имя пакета*
```

Например:

```
import mne, ketas, urllib3
```